# Why is infrared used in thermal imaging and not microwave or radio wave or ultraviolet?

Tags: heat-transfer, radiation, thermal-radiation

In my company, we use IR Thermography.
But I was thinking, why IR? Why not microwave or radio wave or ultraviolet even.
Is it because of some unique property of infrared or the cost-effectiveness?
Or is the thermal imaging also done with other methods other than infrared?

I have little understanding of radiation, so please bear with me.

Comment: Because you are interested in thermal radiation. Its not even just infrared but only a specific subset of infrared that your interested in.

Comment: Are you asking why infrared when all those wavelengths are part of the blackbody spectrum?

Comment: @DKNguyen Yes, that was the question. Why IR and not other wavelengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory you can measure temperatures at different points of a solid item surface and present them with colors on a plot. Collect enough temperatures and plot them accurately enough and that's your manually scanned thermal image.

In many applications that method is not acceptable. For ex. to see an intruder before he knows he's detected you cannot ask him stop for making your pointwise temperature measurements. In such cases thermal cameras are more useful because they work with thermal radiation.

Physicist Max Planck became world famous about 120 years ago by inventing the physical laws behind how the thermal radiation (=generated by the random thermal motion in materials) depends on the temperature - before him the phenomenon was known only experimentally, but it was known.

Actually ultraviolet and visible light could be also be used for thermal imaging, but substantial amounts of them need so high temperatures that nobody could live in such conditions.  Think about red or white hot iron to get a picture. The radiation is strongest in the infrared range in temperatures where we can live.

Microwave emissions caused by thermal motion in materials occur as well, but detecting them needs complex high cost equipment. But the radiation in common temperatures is strongest at infrared range, strongest usually at wavelengths about 10 micrometers.  Microwave emissions of electronic devices would easily cause harm for thermal imaging at microwave range by saturating the imaging devices with overwhelming radiation intensity created by other means than thermal motion.

Microwave thermal imaging is still used for ex. to get some evidence for cosmological theories or to prove them false. The needed equipment for one single image isn't handheld, they can cover square miles.

For better knowledge read these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermography and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation

Answer (score 4):

Because the heat is given off in the infra-red portion of the electro-magnetic spectrum.

That the effects or properties change with frequency change enables us to look at the different things.

You can start here:
https://imagine.gsfc.nasa.gov/science/toolbox/emspectrum1.html